# What does 600R@100M mean from RDA5807M datasheet?

Tags: filter, inductor, components

I’m trying to assemble a bare radio module using RDA5807M IC. The most popular diagram I can find is this:
[image]
What the filter is used on vcc input?
That inductor sign, 600R@100M, what does it mean?

**EDIT:**
as this marked duplicate, i want explain i need just a component which can be placed there, if its an inductor, inductors are specified by **microhenry**, where, how can i find some thing place able in there

Comment: 600 ohm @ 100 MHz. Possibly a ferrite bead or a very small inductor. You can recalculate for inductance if you want, but be aware that most inductors drop off a lot at 100 MHz.

Comment: Using the inductance to specify the ferrite bead is approximately the last thing you want to do; since it's a power rail you want as low an inductance as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the filter is used on vcc input?

It's almost certainly implied to be a ferrite bead

[Here's a good example](http://uk.farnell.com/wurth-elektronik/742792040/ferrite-bead-0805-600-ohm-2a/dp/1635735) of a ferrite bead that has 600 ohm resistive losses at 100 MHz. Ferrites are notably quite lossy as frequency gets above 10 MHz and of course 100 MHz is the middle of the broadcast FM band so it's a suitable design choice in order to keep the power rails of your receiver being "infected" with any 100 MHz: -

[image]

The one above is an SMT 0805 component but there are plenty to choose from. Losses at 1 MHz and below are very, very minor as you can see.

[Here's](http://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/emc-rfi-suppression/ferrites-ferrite-assortments/ferrite-beads?impedance-100mhz=600ohm) the Farnell link to over 200 that meet the spec 600 ohms at 100 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

It's a ferrite bead with an impedance of 600Ω measured at 100MHz.

As to why manufacturers specify impedance at 100MHz, that seems to just be convention.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, i have edited the question, can you please guide me to a certain component, if it can be ferrite bead , i dont found any thing in markets,

Comment: @payam_sbr Digikey, Mouser, Farnell, Avnet, etc. - All have quite literally millions of ferrite bead products. Shopping questions are off topic.